# Send email to different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website where a `interviewer` can send email to `employee` and `candidate` if these two match.

In http://localhost:3000/positions/1/candidatures
 I have access) to the email of all the three ( `interviewer`, `employee` and `candidate`.

I want the `interviewer` to click a button and send an automatic email is sent to `candidate` and `employee`.

I am not sure how to do so.

All the turorials I have seen suggest to create a `application_mailer`
and write in the mailer controller something like:

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

The previous code will send the email to the `@user`. I want the email to be sent to `candidate` and `interviewer`.

In addition, if I create the controller in the base directory, it will never have access to the `candidate` and `interviewer` email.
These two emails are retrievable only in http://localhost:3000/positions/1/candidatures.
(Nested routes)

I am a bit stuck, and would like to know more suggestions

Additional info: `interviewr` and `candidate` are from Devise. While the `employee` is a simple Model.rb

Comment: Normally you just engage your mailer as many times as necessary. You can call one or more notifications per controller request.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I populate the class `class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer` with the two emails I want if they are retrievable only in the path http://localhost:3000/positions/1/candidatures?

Comment: The ApplicationMailer doesn't care about routing or controllers. You engage it from either your model or your controller if/when you want to send email. Like `MyMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver` and so on as per the [usual approach described in the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Answer (score 1):

If `MyMailer` has methods:

```
def candidate_email(interviewer, employee, candidate)
    @interviewer = interviewer
    @employee = employee
    @candidate = candidate

    mail(to: @candidate.email, subject: 'candidate subject')
end

def employee_email(interviewer, employee, candidate)
    @interviewer = interviewer
    @employee = employee
    @candidate = candidate

    mail(to: @employee.email, subject: 'employee subject')
end
```

You can nest an additional controller under `positions`, something like:

```
resources :positions do
    resources :candidatures …
    resources :candidature_notifications, only: :create
end
```

Then in your controller action you can do something like:

```
class CandidatureNotificationsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        # this is probably the similar to what you are loading in Candidatures#index
        @position = Position.find(params[:position_id]
        @interviewer = …
        @employee = …
        @candidate = …

        MyMailer.candidate_email(@interviewer, @employee, @candidate).deliver 
        MyMailer.employee_email(@interviewer, @employee, @candidate).deliver
        # other notifications here

        redirect_to position_candidatures_path(@position), notice: 'Sent notifications'
    end
end
```

And your link on the `/positions/1/candidatures` page will be `<%= link_to 'Send emails', positions_candidature_emails(@position), method: :post %>`